# switching panels - cardlayout

Tags: java, swing, panel, layout-manager, cardlayout

I can't get through panels.

This is the line:

```
cardLayout.show( cards, String.valueOf( "EXCEL_PANEL" ) );
```

I call to show method for `EXCEL_PANEL` and it does not appear.
I feel this is a blinding mistake.

What I want in the end - 
that the entire program will run into the same framework, but I have been stuck for a week with the same problem that I can't realize.

And another question. Does anyone have an idea how to create an event by pressing the Login button and not to continue the rest in this block? Because it's just the beginning and it's annoying.

This is my cardlayout class code:

```
public class CardLayoutManager {

    JPanel cards;
    final static String LOGIN_PANEL = "Card with Login elements";
    final static String EXCEL_PANEL = "Card with Excel load file element";

    public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) throws IOException {

        LoginPanel login_p = new LoginPanel();
        ExcelPanel excel_p = new ExcelPanel();

        cards = new JPanel( new CardLayout() );
        cards.add( login_p, LOGIN_PANEL );
        cards.add( excel_p, EXCEL_PANEL );

        pane.add( cards, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());
        cardLayout.show( cards, String.valueOf( login_p ) );

        login_p.login_btn.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    boolean identification = login_p.LoginCheck();
                    if (!identification) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( login_p, "Sorry, this user does not have access to the system.", "warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE );
                        login_p.ClearFields();
                    } else {
                        cardLayout.show( cards, String.valueOf( "EXCEL_PANEL" ) );
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() throws IOException {
        USTCFrame frame = new USTCFrame();
        CardLayoutManager demo = new CardLayoutManager();
        demo.addComponentToPane( frame.getContentPane() );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel( "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel" );
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
        UIManager.put( "swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE );

        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: My mistake was when I tried to write the name with quotation marks. fixed
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what your classes `USTCFrame`, `LoginPanel` and `ExcelPanel` are.
So I assume `USTCFrame` is a subclass of `JFrame`
and `LoginPanel` and `ExcelPanel` are subclasses of `JPanel`.

Your lines

```
cards = new JPanel( new CardLayout() );
cards.add( login_p, LOGIN_PANEL );
cards.add( excel_p, EXCEL_PANEL );
```

look reasonable. But then your line

```
 cardLayout.show( cards, String.valueOf( login_p ) );
```

doesn't make sense. Instead, it should be

```
cardLayout.show( cards, LOGIN_PANEL );
```

because the second parameter to `cards.show(...)` should be
a String you have used in `cards.add(...)`.

And by the same reason, instead of

```
cardLayout.show( cards, String.valueOf( "EXCEL_PANEL" ) );
```

you should write

```
cardLayout.show( cards, EXCEL_PANEL );
```

Comment: You are right about the classes, USTCFrame is a subclass of JFrame and LoginPanel and ExcelPanel are sub class of JPanel. login opens while excel does not open

Comment: My mistake was when I tried to write the name with quotation marks. fixed
Thank you

Comment: @saliweizman, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.